# how to handle a object type data which contains a string of id's for feeding in my model?

Tags: python, pandas

I am having a dataset in which data type of unique id of a user is in object form. I need to convert it into Int for feeding this data into my model.

here is first rows of my dataset.

```
event_id             event_time        user_ids       tag_from      tag_to
gse:161a4c6b24541287  2018-02-17 17:18:59   user_out_0  0
```

I am trying to convert my "event_id" column into a data type which can be used with ml models.
here is the output of data.info()

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1422907 entries, 0 to 1422906
Data columns (total 5 columns):
event_id      1422907 non-null object
event_time    1422907 non-null datetime64[ns]
user_ids      1422907 non-null object
tag_from      1422907 non-null uint8
tag_to        1422907 non-null uint8
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), object(2), uint8(2)
memory usage: 35.3+ MB}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please proofread & edit your title: "how to a object type data" sounds like gibberish...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you are looking to label encode the `event_id` column. You can either use scikit-learn [label encoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) or pandas:

First convert the `event_id` column to type `category`

```
 df["event_id"] = df["event_id"].astype('category')
```

Then assign the code using

```
df["event_id"] = df["event_id"].cat.codes
```

---

On a separate note, think about how appropriate is it to feed that unique id to your ML model.